# How can I debug css in Ionic2?

Tags: css, debugging, ionic-framework, ionic2

when I debug css from an Ionic app (through "check source" or developer tools) I see source only from one, dynamicly rendered file (main.css). This is hard to check from what file the declaration of strict css value was taken. Now I see something like "main.css:22336" and

```
.menu-content {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

}

I'm almost sure which source file contains this declaration but sometimes it's very hard to find it.

How do you debug your Ionic apps?

Comment: the debugger will only show those css files which are included during the build process.

Comment: Yes, yes, I know but for css-digger sometimes it's very hard (and taking a lot of time) to solve theme problem.

Comment: you can use different index.html, one for your debug app and other for production app. In debug app's index.html, keep every css file seperate so that while debugging you have clear view of which rule is applied from which css file and while creating a production version of app you can use your other index.html where you can combine and minify you css and js files and write rules accordingly in it.

Comment: It's quite difficult and will complicate whole process. Maybe there is a way to put something like comment with name of scss file in values of class. Is there any way to configure build process (i.ex. do not remove comments from scss in process of building  main.css file from scss files)?

Comment: sorry I am not getting what you are saying. if you want to keep comment of scss in css then write comments like this `/*comment*/`

Comment: Yes, indeed, but during build compilator remove all comments and main.css doesn't contain any comment.

Comment: did u try writing your comments like `/*comment*/` if this does not work use this `/*!comment*/` with an exclamation mark in your scss file.

Comment: My mistake - comments are in main.css. All of them. Sorry. They aren't display in debuger mode in browser.

Comment: can u explain in a bit detail what you actually want here.....

Comment: Sorry if I don't write clearly but I try :) I view ionic2 app in browser (firefox or chrome). I press F12 (Developer Tools) and choose html tag from source. I want to change a look of an element (i.ex. font color). In right box I see all css rules of selected element. All of them are in one (automaticly builded before) file - main.css. I don't have any information where is basic scss file which contains that values so I don't know which file should I edit to get my changes (to change color of font).

Comment: I don't think the inspector will be any help for this problem. The only way possible in my view is to maintain multiple css files for each scss for debug mode and combine them to main.css when you are generating release apk.